# jquery bpopup show popup where my link code is a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering if its possible to have my bPopup show up below each of my  links which trigger the popup?

my js:

```
;(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.notesbutton').bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#notesdisplay').bPopup({
            position: [1,1]
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

html:

```
<td align=\"center\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"notesbutton\"><b>Yes</b></a></td>
<div id=\"notesdisplay\">$notes</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the position is taking in an `X` & `Y` access then you should be able to do this.

```
;(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.notesbutton').bind('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#notesdisplay').bPopup({
               position: [event.pageX, event.pageY]
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Try again, it was the `e.preventDefault();` causing that.

Comment: i changed to e.PageX and e.PageY works now.. Thanks!