# jquery bpopup position popup to my #class

Tags: javascript, jquery, bpopup

i asked this similar question before about positioning my jquery bpopup below my link and someone gave me an answer to which it will show the popup where my mouse cursor clicks..this kind of worked until i got a very long page with multiple popups...it stopped working...
This was my old post: 
[jquery bpopup show popup where my link code is a href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19734205/jquery-bpopup-show-popup-where-my-link-code-is-a-href)

To solve my problem, does anyone know how to make bpopup position to a #class? so if my href is:

```
<a href=\"#\" class=\"notesbutton\">Popup</a>
```

I want the popup to show up under the ahref class "notesbutton"

Here is my js code:

```
;(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.notesbutton').bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#notesdisplay').bPopup({
            position: [1,1]
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

html:

```
<a href=\"#\" class=\"notesbutton\"><b>Yes</b></a>
<div id=\"notesdisplay\">$notes</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get your link's position with the `jQuery#offset` method

```
$('.notsbutton').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log({
    x: $(this).offset().left,
    y: $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()
  });
});
```

**NOTE** that you might gonna need to specify `display: inline-block` for your `A` links in order to make the sizes and positioning work correctly in different browsers

Comment: i dont want my links position... i want every popup to show up below my ahref link without linking it to mouse cursor

Comment: em.. isn't that what i suggested? you can get the link's position and height and calculate the position for your bpopup element